# Batch, Get number from text file and write it as a variable

Tags: batch-file

What I'm trying to do is get a **number** from a .txt file and make it a variable.

For example, MyFile.txt contains the number '2', and I need to make the number '2' a variable.

```
for /F "delims=" %%x in ("%USERPROFILE%\MyFile.txt") do set myVar=%%x
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: The content of the file will determine the outcome.. I see no content.

Comment: Your code basically gets the complete (last non-empty) line from the file. We can't guess how that differs from your expectations, so please tell us. Also the content of the file is surely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes in the set list are for processing strings. Either get rid of them entirely or (if you need them because `%USERPROFILE%` contains spaces), add the `usebackq` option.

From the output of `for /?`:

```
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ("string") DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]

    or, if usebackq option present:

FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('string') DO command [command-parameters]
FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (`command`) DO command [command-parameters]
```

---

So in your case, it's either going to be

```
for /F "delims=" %%x in (%USERPROFILE%\MyFile.txt) do set myVar=%%x
```

or

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("%USERPROFILE%\MyFile.txt") do set myVar=%%x
```

but both of these assume that there's only one line in MyFile.txt; otherwise `myVar` is going to get set to whatever the last line of the file is.